# Cloud SQL Postgres Flag: cloudsql.iam_authentication?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

I poked around in the list of Flags that can be used in Postgres in Cloud SQL and I came across this little gem that is in Beta currently: cloudsql.iam_authentication.

I don't see any documentation for it yet, but I wonder if this will let Cloud SQL integrate with IAM similar to what AWS has available for RDS. Even better would be if it could integrate with IAM Groups!

Any one have any information or documentation about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think this new feature is great :D!

Also there are docs for this new feature:

- [Creating and managing users that use IAM database authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-iam-users)
- [Logging in to a database with IAM database authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins)

And also this is very similar to what is in AWS for now. Although this feature is only in PostgreSQL, hope this feature expands to MySQL and SQLServer.

Comment: Thank you YeriPelona! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I successfully tested this out. Enabling the flag does require restarting the instance so be careful if applying it to critical instances.

Comment: This uses OAuth tokens for passwords. These are short lived, ~1 hour, so this functionality requires consistently creating a new one. The documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins) posts the following warning:

Warning: OAuth 2.0 access tokens are short lived and are only valid for one hour. Any new connections or logins created after this time will fail. For this reason, it's not recommended to use IAM database authentication with long-lived processes or applications that rely on connection pooling.